# Debugging Angular 4 in vs code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am writing a web app in Angular 4 and I use VS Code to write the code. I have set VS Code up to work with the Chrome debugger and it all works nicely.

The only thing I find annoying is that when debugging from VS Code it is really difficult to see the output from console.log(). The debug console in VS Code output enormous amounts of information that doesn't seem useful to me like hundreds of line about SourceMap, which makes it really hard to find my few lines of console.log output.

My question is: is there a way to limit the output in the VS Code Debug Console, so I only get relevant information like the one I get in the Chrome Console window?

Comment: are you using any starter pack or using cli to build the project ?

Comment: have you tried `/.vscode/launch.json :: diagnosticLogging: false`?

Comment: @andreim /.vscode/launch.json :: diagnosticLogging: false? works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rahul Good question! Outside VS Code I use CLI. What happens when I run it from inside VS Code, I don't know, but I guess it's also CLI?

Comment: @Gøngevangen lucky guess :) [These examples](https://github.com/roblourens/angular2-tour-of-heroes/blob/master/.vscode/launch.json) helped me providing this answer.